# libjingle talk_base::AsyncSocket() connect failed for Android due to access denied?

Tags: android, sockets

I am using the AsyncSocket source code from libjingle to connect to a server.  I am using the same source code in an iPhone App and the connection is fine, but on the Android phone, I get access denied error when creating a socket.

This is the function that fails at s_ = ::socket(family, type, 0).

```
    // Creates the underlying OS socket (same as the "socket" function).
  virtual bool Create(int family, int type) {
    Close();
    s_ = ::socket(family, type, 0);
    udp_ = (SOCK_DGRAM == type);
    UpdateLastError();
    if (udp_)
      enabled_events_ = DE_READ | DE_WRITE;
    return s_ != INVALID_SOCKET;
  }
```

The family value is 2 and type is 1.  S_ gets a return value of -1 with errno of 13.  I looked up Linux error code and it's access denied.  Do you know if there is any special setting in Android that I need to set?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Permissions?](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html)

Specifically : `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Wade, thanks for the quick help.  I added the permission to the AndroidManifest.xml and it works.